# File.delete() ErrnoException

Tags: java, android, file, android-file

I'm trying to delete internal files and folders in my android app.

The code is correct, but neither files nor folders are removed: `delete()` returns false.

After step-by-step debugging, the debugger took me to "File.java" class in the

```
     catch(ErrnoException errnoException){}
```

block which just returns `false` without any additional explanation.

Could you tell me how to fix this?

**Edit**
now , since i am creating zip archives from folders, zip files are actually deleted with that same function i am using to delete other files !!
i suspect that only files and/or folders created by the application can be deleted by the application but i'm not sure; i tried to share zip archives created from other applications and then i put them in my application folder , they can not be deleted neither can they be shared, when i create archives from my code, these later can be deleted and shared !

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
     * Deletes this file. Directories must be empty before they will be deleted.
     *
     * <p>Note that this method does <i>not</i> throw {@code IOException} on failure.
     * Callers must check the return value.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if this file was deleted, {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean delete() {
        try {
            Libcore.os.remove(path);
            return true;
        } catch (ErrnoException errnoException) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

1. Make sure whether the folder is empty.
2. Make sure whether the file is using by other application.

Try the following code：

```
public static boolean deleteFileSafely(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        String tmpPath = file.getParent() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File tmp = new File(tmpPath);
        file.renameTo(tmp);
        return tmp.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: neither files nor folders are actually deleted, i am using absolute paths to be sure that everything is ok but for now i am really lost.

Comment: May be a problem of no permissions.

Comment: There is no need for any permission to read and write own app data , i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
        File file=new File("yourfilepath");
        String command="rm -r "+file.toString();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

this will excute the command as if you using the cmd or terminal :)

Comment: i will test this tonight, but what the need for all that java apis if such ridiculous thing could not be achieved or at least re throw that ErrnoException so that we can deal or just know what is it about.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably about file permissions. Are you sure that you have permission to delete?

Comment: I do not understand your question, what i know so far is that internal private files can be managed with no special permissions, unlike external files.

Comment: It's very clear actually, are you sure  that the user on the OS, which runs this code, has permission to delete it? This problem seems like a permission problem.

Comment: which permission it should be ? my android test device is rooted i do not think i miss something as a user, i have added test files and folder via an application (FX).

Comment: Check folders delete permission, by `ls -la`.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is as i suspected, i was adding files and folders manually for testings purposes and they have not been deleted, when i create theses files and folders in code, deletion works fine.
however i'm still curious why, is that depending on application context that created theses files , files descriptors or whatever...

anyways, it's working now